# get language id to Drupal 7 Display suite template

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying to add the current node language to the div container of the template file ( I am using Drupal 7 ), here is the current content file I have override:

```
<?php if (isset($title_suffix['contextual_links'])): ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix['contextual_links']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print $ds_content; ?>
```

I want it like so:

```
<div lang='en'>
  <?php if (isset($title_suffix['contextual_links'])): ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix['contextual_links']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print $ds_content; ?>
</div>
```

How can I get the language field where I have only $ds_content variable?

Any help, guide, example or reference appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You get the current node id through this way.

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);

  /** get node language **/ 

  $language = node_load($nid)->language;
}
```

Then pass the language to div

```
<div lang='<?php print $language; ?>'>
  <?php if (isset($title_suffix['contextual_links'])): ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix['contextual_links']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print $ds_content; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The arg() inside is only Array ( [0] => frontpage ) I wish I can get the  id any ideas?

Comment: Yes it's view template page from display suite module.